# Adding Users to Groups in Jfrog's Artifactory using REST API

Tags: perl, artifactory

I need to add users to the groups in Artifactory using REST API. I cannot find any REST API methods available for doing this.I am using PERL scripting to automate Artifactory's REST API calls. Could you please suggest me some ways of doing this? 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what about https://metacpan.org/pod/Artifactory::Client ?

Comment: Thank you for the link @AlexandrEvstigneev, I think these methods are PERL implementations of Artifactory documentation and I cannot find any method to add users to the group in both the places. I am actually new to both Artifactory and PERL, so can you please help me content in "file.xml". Also I need to provide global privileges on all the repositories! How to access all the repositories while creating a permission target are there any group of special chars like we use "select * ...." in DB to do this?. Please help me with this information.

Comment: It is not implementation of documentation, as it said: "Perl client for Artifactory REST API". So if there is an api for this - should be there. If there is not - you should address your question to the Artifactory devs.

Comment: Thanks for the information @AlexandrEvstigneev, will reach out to the Artifactory devs. Could you also provide me with the blog or discussion form for posting my question!

Answer (score 4):

The REST API you're looking for is [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-UpdateGroup) - it uses a json descriptor for operations as specified [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Security+Configuration+JSON).
If you want to see an example of such descriptor use the [get group details](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetGroupDetails) on the specific group you're after (use [get groups](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetGroups) for a list of all your groups).

To add users to specific permission targets you can use [get permission tragets](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetPermissionTargets), [get permission target details](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetPermissionTargetDetails) and [create or replace permission target](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateorReplacePermissionTarget) respectively - [This](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Security+Configuration+JSON)  is the json it uses.

As for client usage - any simple REST client implementation will do of course, you don't have to use an Artifactory specific client for that.

Admin permissions are required for such operations - ask your system admin for these if you are not the admin - it's always better to use the [API key](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Authentication) but basic auth will work as well.

Comment: Thank you @fundeldman for the info, we have actually gone through this REST API methods for group creation and permission targets, but what we are unable to find is how to add the users to these groups once they have been created! Please let us know if you know a way we can do this using REST API after we have created a group.

Comment: That's actually done via the [update user](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-UpdateUser) api - see the json for it [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Security+Configuration+JSON)

Comment: Actually  I have an LDAP user integration, because of which I wont be able to get/ specify the password of the user, which is a mandatory field for updating the profile. Also if I have to create a group called reader with all users added in it is there a way I can do through REST API directly or I will have to go and update all the users' profiles through the above way(which I am sceptical about). Please help me with this info. Thanks in advance

Comment: The user's password is mandatory, yes, but an admin user can achieve this as well so you only need one password - not all of them

Comment: Thank you @fundeldman, one more thing, is there a way other than going and fetching every user we want to add to the group and then modifying his json file to add him to the group, is this the only option available? Or is there any other way we can achieve this? Because I need to create a group with every user in Artifactory, in this case fetching and modifying every user profile is not an efficient way considering the user base we have! And we also have certain scenarios where we have to create a group with around quarter personnel from our user base. Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Not through the API, no - you are welcome to submit a [feature request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira).  As an alternative to your use case you can either modify the security.xml descriptor with everything you want, or better yet, use LDAP groups [import](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/LDAP+Groups#LDAPGroups-SynchronizingLDAPGroupswithArtifactory) to do all the work for you.

Comment: It's too bad you only mentioned LDAP now as groups import is probably what you're looking for - after the LDAP groups are synced with Artifactory you can assign them permission targets as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the information @fundeldman, though I have to say I am disappointed that there is no way of doing this using REST API.

Comment: Why do you need REST if LDAP group sync does exactly what you need..?

Comment: Actually we have to create certain groups at Artifactory level after the LDAP integration is done, for which we want to add the users. Anyways I just am thinking, what is the use of creating groups using REST API if you are unable to add any users to them using the same REST API. Doesn't it feel like something is missing?